# How do I connect a software API (WhipAround) to Google Sheets?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, connection, syntax-error

I'm having trouble connecting an API to Google sheets.

Using this Fetch/Request, how would I get a connection to Google Sheets using Apps Script?

```
const options = {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    accept: 'application/json',
    'X-API-KEY': 'MyKey'
  }
};

fetch('https://api.whip-around.com/api/public/v4/work-orders?limit=20&page=1', options)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(response => console.log(response))
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

I tried this in Google Apps Script, but it's not working

```
function fetchDataFromAPI() {
  var apiUrl = 'https://api.whip-around.com/api/public/v4/work-orders';
  var headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer MyKey'
  };
  
  var options = {
    'headers': headers
  };

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(apiUrl, options);
  var responseData = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  
  // Now you can manipulate the API data and update your Google Sheet
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var numRows = responseData.length;
  var numCols = responseData[0].length;
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, numRows, numCols).setValues(responseData);
}
```

[image]

Comment: If your Javascript works fine and you want to convert from your Javascript to Google Apps Script, I think that it is required to include `accept: 'application/json', 'X-API-KEY': 'MyKey'` into the request header instead of `'Authorization': 'Bearer MyKey'`. But, I do not know your API. So, even when the script for requesting works, I cannot propose the modification of the below script of `UrlFetchApp.fetch`. I apologize for this. So, can you provide the sample value of `response` of `.then(response => console.log(response))`? And also, can you provide the official document of your API?

Comment: Is this what the changes you mean?

`function fetchDataFromAPI() {
  var apiUrl = 'https://api.whip-around.com/api/public/v4/work-orders';
  var headers = {
    Accept: 'application/json','mykey'
  };
  
  var options = {
    'headers': headers
  };
`

Also, here's the link to the documentation: https://whiparound-public-api.readme.io/reference/get_api-public-v4-work-orders

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, it seems that unfortunately, you couldn't correctly understand my comment. I think that the reason for that you cannot correctly understand my comment is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill. So, I proposed an answer. But, I cannot know your expected situation on the Spreadsheet. So, I modified just the script for requesting your API. I think that this is also due to my poor English skill. I really apologize for my poor English skill again.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to convert your showing Javascript to Google Apps Script.

#### Modification points:

- If your Javascript works fine and you want to convert from your Javascript to Google Apps Script, I think that it is required to include `accept: 'application/json', 'X-API-KEY': 'MyKey'` into the request header instead of `'Authorization': 'Bearer MyKey'`.
- About your following reply,

  > Is this what the changes you mean? function fetchDataFromAPI() {   var apiUrl = 'https://api.whip-around.com/api/public/v4/work-orders';   var headers = {     Accept: 'application/json','mykey'   };      var options = {     'headers': headers   };  Also, here's the link to the documentation: whiparound-public-api.readme.io/reference/…

  - I'm worried that you couldn't correctly understand my comment.

In this case, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function fetchDataFromAPI() {
  var yourAPIkey = "###"; // Please set your API key.

  var apiUrl = 'https://api.whip-around.com/api/public/v4/work-orders?limit=20&page=1';
  var options = { headers: { "X-API-KEY": yourAPIkey, accept: "application/json" } };
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(apiUrl, options);
  var responseData = response.getContentText();
  console.log(responseData); // Here, you can see the response value in the log.
}
```

#### Note:

- In this modification, it supposes that your Javascript works fine. Please be careful about this. If your Javascript didn't work, please confirm your API key again.
- Unfortunately, from your reply and your question, I couldn't understand your output situation. So, in this answer, I modified just the script for requesting your API.